Detect row change by group and bring result back to original data frame
Here is my example. I am grouping, ordering and detecting change from one row to another.
import pandas as pd
import datetime

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                      'col2': [2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5],
                      'col3': [datetime.date(2023, 2, 1),
                               datetime.date(2023, 3, 1),
                               datetime.date(2023, 5, 1),
                               datetime.date(2023, 4, 1),
                               datetime.date(2023, 3, 1),
                               datetime.date(2023, 2, 1),
                               datetime.date(2023, 4, 1)]})

my_df_temp = my_df.sort_values(by=['col3']).groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(
    lambda x: x != x.shift(1)
).reset_index(name='col2_change')

Now I would like to bring result back to my_df i.e. I would like my_df to have column col2_change.
Simple assignment will not work my_df['col2_change'] = my_df_temp.col2_change.values
One way I can do it is by ordering my_df by two columns col1 and col3 and then simply assigning, but it looks a bit laborious. Is there an easier way to do it?

my_df["col2_change"] = my_df.sort_values(by=['col3']).groupby('col1', sort=False)['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift(1))) would also work (Disabling groupby sort preserves the original index), but using transform is a better method.

Your method is actually quite good, but if you what a more concise method that also elimnates the overhead of resetting, you can do this:
import pandas as pd
import datetime

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                      'col2': [2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5],
                      'col3': [datetime.date(2023, 2, 1),
                               datetime.date(2023, 3, 1),
                               datetime.date(2023, 5, 1),
                               datetime.date(2023, 4, 1),
                               datetime.date(2023, 3, 1),
                               datetime.date(2023, 2, 1),
                               datetime.date(2023, 4, 1)]})

my_df['col2_change'] = (
    my_df.sort_values(by='col3')
    .groupby('col1')['col2']
    .transform(lambda x: x != x.shift(1))
)

print(my_df)

which gives
  col1  col2        col3  col2_change
0    a     2  2023-02-01         True
1    a     2  2023-03-01        False
2    a     3  2023-05-01         True
3    a     2  2023-04-01        False
4    b     5  2023-03-01        False
5    b     5  2023-02-01         True
6    b     5  2023-04-01        False

transform broadcasts group-level operations back to the original dataframewhich is more efficient in many cases.

Code
As everyone seems to agree, you don't need apply. And in my opinion, you don't need transform either, because pandas series operates comparisons on index anyway.
my_df['col2_change'] = (
    my_df.sort_values('col3')
         .groupby('col1')['col2'].shift()
         .ne(my_df['col2'])
)

